# How to get HTML Document height using CEFSHARP?

Tags: vb.net, document, cefsharp

I'm changing a web browser  application to use the CEFSHARP chromium based browser instead of the inbuilt vb.net web browser control and need to query the html document to be able to set the browser control height to the height of the html page. In the VB web browser control I've used the following to set the height.

```
    WebBrowser.Height = WebBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height
    WebBrowser.Height = WebBrowser.RectangleToScreen
```

How can you get the HTML document properties in CEFSHARP?  I have been looking through a number for threads and it seems to be that you need to do a javascript call but I'm unable to find a simple example. Anyone have any experience trying to do this with CEFSHARP?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#2-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-that-returns-a-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code I'm attempting to use to get the height of the HTML document but it doesn't work. I'm fairly sure its the script line that is wrong but cant seem to find the right syntax to just get the document height.

```
Private Sub WWWBrowser_LoadingState(sender As Object, e As LoadingStateChangedEventArgs) Handles WWWBrowser.LoadingStateChanged

    If e.IsLoading = False Then

        Dim script = "(function() { var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement; return  Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight ); })();"
        Dim task As Task(Of JavascriptResponse) = WWWBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script)
        Dim taskResult As String

        task.ContinueWith(
            Sub(t)
                If t.IsFaulted = False Then
                    Dim response = t.Result 'Error: Result is not a member of Task' 
                    If response.Success And response.Result IsNot Nothing Then
                        taskResult = response.Result
                    End If
                End If
            End Sub)

        MsgBox(task.Result.Result)

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Run the script in `DevTpols` see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Comment: Your script doesn't actually match the example, you've subtly modified it.

Comment: I have edited your answer to include the corrected javascript

Comment: Thanks for your help - I got it working -Javascript is not strong point for me.